# share wired connection to wifi adapter ( external )

Tags: wireless, sharing, network-bridge, wired, subnet

I'm connected to the internet using wired connection and I have an external

TP-LINK wifi adapter. I want to bridge connection from wired to wifi adapter,

then to my iPhone. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It does it automatically. Just create a hotspot with ubuntu. Go to **System Settings>Network>Wireless** The just use "Use as hotspot"

[image: Screenshot]